# Arc Length of a Cardioid $r=2\sin{\theta}-2$; Issue with Bounds of Integration

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, substitution, arc-length

Good morning.  I am trying to find the arc length of the cardioid $r=2\sin{\theta}-2$.  After plugging in $r$ and $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ into the arc length formula we get

$$s=\int_\alpha^\beta\sqrt{(2\sin\theta-2)^2+(2\cos\theta)^2}d\theta=2\sqrt{2}\int_\alpha^\beta{\sqrt{1-\sin\theta}} d\theta$$

It appears from a graphing calculator that the bounds of integration cover the principal angles $0\le\theta<2\pi$.  Using an identity

$$\sqrt{1-\sin\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin^2\theta}{1+\sin\theta}}=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1+\sin\theta}}$$

This gives me the integral

$$s=2\sqrt{2}\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1+\sin\theta}}} d\theta$$

So now to solve I make a $u$-substitution.  Let $u=1+\sin\theta$.  Then $du=\cos\theta d\theta$.  But if $\theta=0$, $u=1$.  And if $\theta=2\pi$, then also $u=1$.  This creates a situation where the bounds of integration are the same, which makes a calculation of $0$ for the final answer.  So where did I go wrong?

Comment: Which formula do you used? $$\int \sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}d\theta$$?

Comment: Yes.  Under the radical i got $$(2\sin\theta-2)^2+(2\cos\theta)^2$$ and when I expand, I get $$4\sin^2\theta-8\sin\theta+4+4\cos^2\theta$$ which reduces to $8-8\sin\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT...You can, by consideration of the symmetry of the polar graph in the $y$ axis, rewrite this integral as $$s=\color{red}{2\times}2\sqrt{2}\int_{\color{red}{-\frac{\pi}{2}}}^{\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1+\sin\theta}}} d\theta$$

Now the bounds for $u$ are straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use $$\sin(\theta)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$ and $$d\theta=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$$

Comment: Is this really the easiest way?  For someone in a calculus class this seems completely out of left field.

Comment: It is the so called Weierstrass substitution

Comment: I don't know if it is the easiest way, but a way and you can solve your problem

Comment: After looking at the graph, I think it might be easier to exploit the symmetry of the cardiod and multiply the integral by 2 and use bounds $\pi/2$ to $3\pi/2$?

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier if you do\begin{align}1-\sin\theta&=\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)-\sin\theta\\&=\sin\left(\left(\frac\pi4+\frac\theta2\right)+\left(\frac\pi4-\frac\theta2\right)\right)-\sin\left(\left(\frac\pi4+\frac\theta2\right)-\left(\frac\pi4-\frac\theta2\right)\right)\\&=2\sin\left(\frac\pi4+\frac\theta2\right)\cos\left(\frac\pi4-\frac\theta2\right)\\&=2\sin\left(\frac\pi4+\frac\theta2\right)\cos\left(\frac\pi2-\left(\frac\pi4+\frac\theta2\right)\right)\\&=2\sin^2\left(\frac\pi4+\frac\theta2\right),\end{align}from wich you deduce that$$\sqrt{1-\sin\theta}=\sqrt2\left|\sin\left(\frac\pi4+\frac\theta2\right)\right|.$$