# Arc-Length of Curves

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I want to calculate the arc length of a full cycle(? by this I mean from $t=0$ to $t=2\pi$) of a cardioid. The parameterization of a cardioid is given by:
$$
\gamma(t)=(2\cos(t)-\cos(2t),2\sin(t)-\sin(2t))
\\
|\gamma'| = \sqrt{8-8\cos(t)}
$$

And thus, the arc length of a full cycle/rotation is:
$$
\int^{2\pi}_0 \sqrt{8-8\cos(t)} dt.
$$

Which is non-negative. That is why I don't *think* we need to take the absolute value of the function. The issue, why am I getting $0$ as the value of the integral? Furthermore, to tackle this, because of symmetry, I tried to take $\int^\pi_0 |\gamma'|dt$ instead, then multiply it by 2. However, the result of this integral is negative. What? A non-negative function everywhere has a negative integral?

**Edit**:
$$
u = 8+8cos(t) \Rightarrow \frac{du}{dt} = -8sin(t),
\\
\int^{2\pi}_0 \sqrt{8-8cos(t)}dt = \int^{2\pi}_0 \sqrt{8-8cos(t)} \frac{\sqrt{8+8cos(t)}}{\sqrt{8+8cos(t)}}dt=
\\
=\int^{a'}_{a''}\frac{|8sin(t)|}{\sqrt{u}}\cdot\frac{1}{-8sin(t)}du
$$
Now, I think I realize my mistake. I should separate this into 2, from $0$ to $\pi$, and from $\pi$ to $2\pi$. The final result would be

$$
\int^0_{16} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du + \int^{16}_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du
$$

Note that $a':= u = 8 + 8cos(\pi)=0, a'':= 8 + 8cos(0) = 16$ for the first integral, and $a':= u = 8 + 8cos(2\pi)=16, a'':= 8 + 8cos(pi) = 0$

So, the final answer will be 16.

Comment: Since we don't know *how* you got $0$ as the value of the integral, how can we answer your question *why* you got that answer? I suggest you show us how you actually calculated that, so that we can answer your question. Otherwise, it's not clear what you are actually asking.

Comment: The cycloid is "tricky" because the integrand you get after substitution (to deal with the square-root) changes sign between  quadrants:  that's why your definite integral came to zero.  Integrate only from $ \ 0 \ $ to $ \ \pi/2 \ $ and then multiply by the appropriate factor.

Comment: I've edited @LeeMosher

Comment: Oh! What a stupid mistake..

Comment: @boojum: That looks like a good answer.

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes Your result should be correct now; the arc length of a full cycle of a cycloid of radius $ \ R \ $ is $ \ 8R \ \ . $ I know about this particular arc-length integral because I've had students come to me frantically with the same question you had -- it is not a "stupid" mistake.  You learn from experience to watch for integrands that change sign over an interval/region of integration.  Stewart's textbook has this arc-length calculation as a brief example and, until maybe the most recent editions, left the "trip-hazard" concerning cancelation between quadrants unremarked.

Comment: This sort of situation is encountered with many sorts of parametric and polar curves.  Here's another problem with a student running into the same issue:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758767/arc-length-of-a-cardioid-r-2-sin-theta-2-issue-with-bounds-of-integration?rq=1

Comment: I would say: _avoid answering questions in questions_ and formulate as _your own answer_ instead. This prevents the question from popping up again and again as being unanswered (in my MSE newsfeed).